# What is the best way to handle backend in flutter? Can it be linked with django?

Tags: django, rest, flutter

I was researching and I could not find a proper solution. If you have some examples, please also explain why.

Comment: it would be linked with any back-end which offers an API

Comment: Hi Sudip! welcome to stackoverflow and please notice that this is not a proper question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Some help: You can use dart http package or dio package or dart httpClient to do network requests.

Answer (score 0):

"Best way" of handling Flutter backend is a bit subjective as this will still depend on the experience of the developer/s or the team that will be handling the project.

Just like any other backend, one of the primary options we have to communicate it with our Flutter apps is thru REST APIs.

If you are using django, which I hope you do, you can use the package [djangorestframework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to expose API endpoints containing your data models from your database, presented in a JSON format.

Please visit this link in your browser (hope you got your JSON extension w/ you) or in Postman:

https://api.github.com/users/joshuadeguzman

You should then see the following output.

```
/ 20191230121253
// https://api.github.com/users/joshuadeguzman

{
  "login": "joshuadeguzman",
  "id": 20706361,
  "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjIwNzA2MzYx",
  "avatar_url": "https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/20706361?v=4",
  "gravatar_id": "",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/users/joshuadeguzman",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/joshuadeguzman",
  "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/joshuadeguzman/followers",
  "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/joshuadeguzman/following{/other_user}",
  "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/joshuadeguzman/gists{/gist_id}",
  "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/joshuadeguzman/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
  "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/joshuadeguzman/subscriptions",
  "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/joshuadeguzman/orgs",
  "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/joshuadeguzman/repos",
  "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/joshuadeguzman/events{/privacy}",
  "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/joshuadeguzman/received_events",
  "type": "User",
  "site_admin": false,
  "name": "Joshua de Guzman",
  "company": "@freelancer",
  "blog": "jdg.ph",
  "location": "Manila, PH",
  "email": null,
  "hireable": true,
  "bio": "Software Engineer at @freelancer. Building tools for humans.",
  "public_repos": 98,
  "public_gists": 39,
  "followers": 75,
  "following": 21,
  "created_at": "2016-07-28T15:19:54Z",
  "updated_at": "2019-12-29T02:28:50Z"
}
```

Next thing you want to do is to parse this JSON string so that you can use it (as objects) in your Flutter App.

You can use the [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) plugin for that.

Example request

```dart
Future<http.Response> fetchGithubProfile(String username) {
  return http.get('https://api.github.com/users/$');
}
```

Some articles you can read:

- https://medium.com/flutter-community/django-search-flutter-1cb3e8a5db1a
- https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data
- https://alligator.io/flutter/flutter-http/

I also wrote an article on how you can setup Django + Django Rest Framework:

- https://dev.to/joshuadeguzman/definitive-guide-developing-restful-apis-using-python-django-and-drf-2h7e

Some example apps that might help you:

- https://github.com/ReeceRose/django-flutter-todo (Django + Flutter)
- https://github.com/joshuadeguzman/flutter-moviehub (Demonstrates usage of http package with BLoC)